# Java EE 8 MVC: How do you startup with controller?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jakarta-mvc

I am aware that Java EE 8 MVC is shiny and new and might not have everything
I hoping there is a way to call a view from a controller on startup

```
@Path("home")
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @Inject
    Models models;

    @Inject
    public UIAccess uiaccess;

    @GET
    @Path("index")
    public String index() {
        models.put("sidebar", uiaccess.sideBar());
        return "home/index.xhtml";
    }    
}
```

Is there any way that the *web.xml* can be setup to call the view

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>app/home/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

This does not work ***app/controller_name/view*** when place in the *web.xml*

I know servlet class can be called in startup but want about controllers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I encountered same problem before, web.xml seems doesn't support for MVC path yet.

My opinion you may select 2 option below

1. Use JSP or html as welcome file.
2. Use MVC as default handler and set as root context. you may learn more by [sample](https://github.com/Victz/mvc).